# Combine macros to filter on today's and tomorrow's date

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro7()
    With Worksheets("STG_SB_OPICS_DTL")
        With .Range(.Cells(4, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterToday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
    
Sub Macro8()
    With Worksheets("STG_SB_OPICS_DTL")
        With .Range(.Cells(4, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterTomorrow, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
    
Sub TodayTomorrow()
    Call Macro7
    Call Macro8
End Sub
```

Hi, the original problem is fixed. But I can't seem to combine these two macros into one.

So, for the dynamic filter, once I press the macro code for `TodayTomorrow()`, I wanted it to sort to todays and tomorrow date and not just today.

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: The first problem is that you are missing the colons for `field:=4` and `Criteria1:=xlFilterToday` - once that is fixed you will want to verify that `4` is the correct value for `field` - You will notice that if you change it to `1` for example, it does not error.

Comment: Hi, looks really great! Turns out the error is in my party of the field and the semicolons. Questions: If I do have a macro to filter to todays data and tomorrow(individually), and want it to run it together, any suggestion? I'll edit my post to show the code, thanks

Comment: Hi, it looks great, tysm. However, I have an issue with the code that I would want to clarify.    '~~> Identify your filter range
        Set rng = .Range("D4:D" & lRow)
        In that section, I have to manually type the row of the data that is received that day in order for it to adapt. Say data of 12 January today is 900, I have to change it to "D900:D". Any tips to make it dynamic? Thanks beforehand

Comment: Additionally, the format of data that I receives is Date 00:00:00, e.g: 11/01/2024 0:00:00

Comment: nevermind, I used a macro to replace all to change it according to the date format. Thank you Siddhath, I'll close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter on today's and tomorrow's date then you can try this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim TodaysDate As Date
    Dim TomorrowsDate As Date
    
    '~~> Today's date
    TodaysDate = Date
    '~~> Tomorrow's date
    TomorrowsDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("STG_SB_OPICS_DTL")
    
    With ws
        '~~> Remove any existing filter
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Find last row in Col D
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Identify your filter range
        Set rng = .Range("D4:D" & lRow)
        
        '~~> Filter
        With rng
            .AutoFilter field:=1, _
            Criteria1:="=" & TodaysDate, _
            Operator:=xlOr, _
            Criteria2:="=" & TomorrowsDate
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Note**: If you wish you can also use `xlAnd` instead of `xlOr`. In that case, the code becomes.

```
'~~> Filter
With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & TodaysDate, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="<=" & TomorrowsDate
End With
```